# Python Request Post Loop através do arquivo Json

Tags: python, json, api, loop, post

Estou tentando construir um script que pegará cada objeto json que tenho e executará um request.post com sucesso (um por um) até que seja concluído.

```
{
"cost_center": [
    {
        "code": "0",
        "name": "teste0"
    },
    {
        "code": "1010",
        "name": "teste1"
    },
    {
        "code": "2020",
        "name": "teste2"
    },
    {
        "code": "3030",
        "name": "teste3"
    }
]
}
```

o problema aqui é que ele tentará fazer o posto tudo de uma vez e eu preciso fazer um por um

Exemplo:  "cost_center": [{"code": "0","name": "teste0"} (cadastrado com sucesso!)
Ai o entra o loop para fazer o mesmo no próximo.

Como posso fazer isso para iterar e também postar o próximo objeto json?

Meu codigo:

```
with open ("response_cost_center.json",'r') as arquivo:
        cent = json.load (arquivo)
        
url = "https://api.pontomais.com.br/external_api/v1/cost_centers"   
payload = json.dumps(cent) 
        
for item in cent:
    try:
        headers
        url
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        print(response.text)
        break  
    except:
        print('ERROR')
```

Obrigado por qualquer conselho com antecedência. Peço desculpas se meu código estiver ruim.

Answer (score 0):

Tens que especificar a chave da lista e criar o payload para cada item.

```
for item in cent['cost_center']:
    payload = json.dumps(item)
```